# Which "using" should I use for having Session/Request in a class?

Tags: c#, .net, class, webforms

I'm with a .NET/C# WebForm application.
I create a class, and I'd like to use the object `Session` or `Request` (as I use on an .aspx page) without prefix it with `HttpContext.Current`.

I guess I can just import a class by using? But which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To obtain `Request`, `Session` etc in an unrelated class without using `HttpContext.Current` first... well, *you can't* - unless you add them as properties somewhere - for example:

```
protected static HttpRequest Request {
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Request; }
}
```

However, frankly I don't think I *would* do this. In fact, I would strongly advise limiting how much your utility code knows about the request model, and simply figure out *what the class needs to know*, and give it exactly that. Let the UI layer worry about ASP.NET, not your logic code.

Answer (score 1):

why not declare a variable: Session=HttpContext.Current.Session ?

Answer (score 0):

using System.Web

Also you'll need to add reference to it.

Milos

Comment: The question is not "how to obtain `HttpContext.Current`"; it is "how to obtain `Session`, `Request` etc *without* using `HttpContext.Current`"

Answer (score 0):

By using this `System.Web.SessionState` you can access the session.
[More information on this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx) 
Namespace:  System.Web.SessionState
Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)